# Dyno hours of crashed workers and idle web applications

Tags: heroku

'1. I currently have 1 worker dyno doing background work. I does so every day for about an hour. The rest of the time the worker dyno recognizes, that it has nothing to do and terminates. The dyno manager will respawn the dyno and after a few seconds the dyno will terminate.

It is not clear to me how this will count in computing hours, esepecially as

https://dashboard.heroku.com/account

Shows "Not available" in the current usage statistics.

The Scheduler addon doesn't seem to be the right tool for me, as they are meant for to schedule short running background tasks (according to the description)

Q1: How does a crashed worker process consume dyno hours?

'2. How is my web app being charged when idle? The documentation says "A web dyno that is idled continues to accrue usage. To stop accruing usage, you must scale the web dyno to 0". This means that an idle web app is using the same dyno hours or at a reduced rate? "continues to accrue usage" would suggest some lower rate but isn't clear out of context.

Q2: To what rate does an idling web worker consume dyno hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my understanding: Heroku does not differentiate between the Dyno types when it comes to pricing. An idled Dyno will produce the same cost like a running Dyno. But Heroku says on their website: "... Workers dynos are never idled out."
A crashed Dyno will constantly try to restart with a 10 minute break (after restart fails twice in a row).

Comment: Ok, so an idle web app will be fully charged. But > a crashed Dyno will constantly try to restart with a 10 minute break (after restart fails twice in a row).  <--- I know, but is the time between the crash charged or not?

Comment: A crashed dyno is still billed for. I can't help but find this irrelevant since your dynos should not be crashing all the time :P

Comment: Ok, thank you. My dyno is crashing, because it only has work between 22 and 23 o'clock and the scheduler is not suitable for my thing. Now that it will be billed anyway, I will not exit but simply continue idling.